# Can you sync computer with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

When having one computer, it works great syncing your iphone with it, to get your stuff on the iPhone. However, having two computers, one at work and one at home, I wonder if it's possible to have a relationship like this:

```
 Computer 1 > iPhone > Computer 2
```

instead of the two computers battling against each other and removing files etc they don't have? It would be great if you could do this automatically, so I don't have to manually transfer files etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an article on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5064933/sync-an-iphone-with-multiple-computers) about this issue: How to sync an iPhone with two (or more) Computers.

> Plug your iPhone into a variety of
>   computers, yours or other people's,
>   and you'll find that your phone and
>   iTunes want to wipe everything clean
>   and start over, every single time.
>   [**Andrew Grant at the Shiny Things blog**](http://www.andrewgrant.org/2008/03/30/how-to-sync-an-iphone-with-two-or-more-computers.html)
>   shows how to edit your iTunes Music
>   Library XML file to sync your phone
>   (or iPod touch) with different
>   systems. That means you can, say,
>   auto-grab just your music from your
>   Mac at home, but grab Contacts and
>   Calendars from your work PC. The guide
>   requires very little hacking, and
>   Grant provides links to simple text
>   and hex editors to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Macs, MobileMe makes this pretty easy (although it is not cheap).  I have my iPhone, iPad, and three Macs synched this way.

MobileMe sorta works with Windows too, but I don't have enough experience to recommend it.